# R: Number of obs between min and max

Tags: r

I need to extract the number of observations between min and max.  I know that I can subset the data, creating a new DF then calculate length but am interested in a less involved process.  For example, I have and would like number of observations from min to max,

```
 ddd <- mydf[,list(minVar1 = min(Var1, na.rm=TRUE),
         maxVar1 = max(Var1, na.rm=TRUE)), by="Group"]
```

Is there a direct approach without an intermediate DF?  Thanks.

Edit: I guess this is a bit more complicated than originally stated.  For Group = 1, the minimum value is actually 2 however I need minimum indexed lower than max value index/position.  So, that range is 3 to 7 for a length of 3.  The Idx variable scores the measured index/position of Var1. So, max position of Var1 must be first identified, then insure that the min position is extracted from Idx less than that of the max position.

```
Group Var1 Idx
1 3 4
1 5 5
1 7 6
1 3 7
1 2 8
2 5 12
2 6 13
2 9 14
2 11 15
2 5 16

Group min max length
1 3 7 3
2 5 11 4
```

Comment: Looks like you are using `data.table` syntax.  Please show some example and expected output.

Comment: Interesting question. Here is a base R solution with the `mtcars` dataset (for the variable `hp` for example):  `length(unique(mtcars[order(mtcars$hp), "hp"]))`

Comment: What if there are ties?  It is not clear about the number of observations.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the reason why you are changing the min value from 2 to 3.

Comment: @ksing Why is `length` equal to 4 for `Group` 2, and not 2 (5 < {6, 9} < 11)?

Comment: The more the OP edit the question the less clear it becomes @nrussell

Comment: @SabDeM Agreed; I'm also not clear on why 3 is being used for the minimum of  `Group` 1.

Comment: I need minimum to have a lower Idx than max hence 3 is minimum in Group 1.  As for the length of Group 2 that 15 - 12 + 1 (inclusive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `data.table`, we could get the expected output.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Grouped by 'Group', we `order` the 'Idx', get the position of the maximum value of 'Var1' ('ind'), then we get the position of minimum value of 'Var1' that is lower than 'ind' ('ind2').  We summarise and create the columns 'min' and 'max' by indexing 'ind2' and 'ind' on 'Var1' while the 'length' is created by the taking the difference of 'Idx' using the same 'ind', 'ind2' and adding 1.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[order(Idx), {ind <- which.max(Var1)
                       ind2=which.min(Var1[seq(ind)])
                       list(min=Var1[ind2], 
                            max=Var1[ind], 
                            length=Idx[ind]-Idx[ind2]+1)} , Group]
#   Group min max length
#1:     1   3   7      3
#2:     2   5  11      4
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try.  It looks like i tried the following weeks ago `maxVar1 <- mydf[, .SD[which.max(Var1)], by = "Group"]`, `maxIdxVar1 <- maxindexVar1[ ,list(Group, Idx)]`, `minVar1 <- mydf[, .SD[which.min(Var1)], by = "Group"]`, `minIdxVar1 <- minindexVar1[ ,list(Group, Idx)]`.  So, that just identifies the min and max Idx of Var1.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(Group) %>%
        summarise(min = min(Var1[1:which.max(Var1)]),
                  max = max(Var1), 
                  diff = 1 + which.max(Var1) - which.min(Var1[1:which.max(Var1)]))

Source: local data frame [2 x 4]

  Group min max diff
1     1   3   7    3
2     2   5  11    4
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll give this a try.